# Why am I getting Guru Meditation -79 (VERR_INVALID_STATE) in VirtualBox?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

I've been running a guest OS in VirtualBox and, while I was doing some stuff in my host OS, the computer locked up. So, I had to reboot from the ON/OFF button of my laptop.

After that, whenever I try to run the guest OS in VirtualBox, I get the guru meditation error.

I've been searching for the solution on the Internet, but I couldn't solve it yet.

Virtualization is enabled on the BIOS menu, RAM memory for the guest OS is set to 1GB (my computer has 8GB RAM), and even so it doesn't work. I've also tried to reinstall VirtualBox and delete and import again the virtual machine image but no success.

Here I attach an excerpt of the log data file:

```
00:00:00.953342 VMEmt: Halt method global1 (5)
00:00:00.953439 VMEmt: HaltedGlobal1 config: cNsSpinBlockThresholdCfg=2000
00:00:00.953455 Changing the VM state from 'CREATING' to 'CREATED'
00:00:00.954529 SharedFolders host service: Adding host mapping
00:00:00.954541     Host path '/home/aaron/Trabajo/PSE4RAW', map name 'vagrant', writable, automount=false, automntpnt=, create_symlinks=true, missing=false
00:00:00.954948 Changing the VM state from 'CREATED' to 'POWERING_ON'
00:00:00.955002 AIOMgr: Endpoints without assigned bandwidth groups:
00:00:00.955010 AIOMgr:     /home/aaron/VirtualBox VMs/PSE4RAW_default_1643020476130_80381/box-disk001.vmdk
00:00:00.955109 Changing the VM state from 'POWERING_ON' to 'RUNNING'
00:00:00.955124 Console: Machine state changed to 'Running'
00:00:00.956684 Changing the VM state from 'RUNNING' to 'GURU_MEDITATION'
00:00:00.956703 Console: Machine state changed to 'GuruMeditation'
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
00:00:00.956894 !!
00:00:00.956894 !!         VCPU0: Guru Meditation -79 (VERR_INVALID_STATE)
00:00:00.956898 !!
00:00:00.956902 !!
00:00:00.956903 !! {mappings, <NULL>}
00:00:00.956903 !!
00:00:00.956913 !!
00:00:00.956913 !! {hma, <NULL>}
00:00:00.956914 !!
00:00:00.956915 Hypervisor Memory Area (HMA) Layout: Base 00000000a0000000, 0x02800000 bytes
00:00:00.956917 00000000a06c7000-00000000a06e8000 00007f187aaab000 ffffa95341e65000 LOCKED                   alloc once (PGM_PHYS)
00:00:00.956921 00000000a06b9000-00000000a06c7000 00007f18b0033000 ffffa95341ce1000 LOCKED                   alloc once (VMM)
00:00:00.956922 00000000a06ab000-00000000a06b9000 00007f18b8006000 ffffa95341b49000 LOCKED                   alloc once (VMM)
00:00:00.956924 00000000a02aa000-00000000a06ab000 00007f187a0d3000 ffffa95346d0b000 LOCKED                   alloc once (PGM_PHYS)
00:00:00.956926 00000000a027b000-00000000a02aa000 00007f18b0041000 ffffa953441a1000 LOCKED                   alloc once (PGM_POOL)
00:00:00.956927 00000000a0278000-00000000a027b000 00007f18c41ac000 ffffa953403ab000 LOCKED                   alloc once (CPUM_CTX)
00:00:00.956929 00000000a0038000-00000000a0278000 00007f187a81c000 ffffa953468c9000 LOCKED                   Heap
00:00:00.956931 00000000a0023000-00000000a0038000 00007f18b8026000 ffffa95341eb3000 LOCKED                   VMCPU
00:00:00.956932 00000000a000e000-00000000a0023000 00007f18b803b000 ffffa95341e9d000 LOCKED                   VMCPU
00:00:00.956934 00000000a0000000-00000000a000e000 00007f18b8050000 ffffa95341e8d000 LOCKED                   VM
00:00:00.956935 !!
00:00:00.956936 !! {cpumguest, verbose}
00:00:00.956936 !!
```

I hope you can help me and thank you in advance!